# German umlauts in jspdf

Tags: jspdf

is there a way to handle german umlauts in jsPDF? They are not rendered correctly, instead I get some unreadable symbols.

Best regards,

Stefan Lindmayer

Comment: Could be https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/12

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898106/portuguese-spanish-accents-with-jspdf

Answer (score 1):

Another user worked this out:

The problem is caused by the Base64 encoding lib which converts the document to UTF8 while the PDF itself states that it uses "WinAnsiEncoding".

For him it was solved by commenting out the following line in libs/base64.js:

input = Base64._utf8_encode(input);

Maybe that will work for you too.

Kind regards,

Chris

Comment: Thanks for your reply Chris. I have read this post as well but I can't find this Piece of code. Maybe this user had another version of jsPDF or I am just too stupid.

Comment: can't find this line in the newest jspdf version. searched all js files included in the package.  --> I know it has to work somehow with umlaut as the editor/preview page that comes with the package displays it correctly - i copied all script includes from that example and included them in mine, but it still dont work

Answer (score -2):

You also could also just use 
`ü = ue` `ö = oe` `ä = ae`
that should work.