# accents with jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I already checked this post [Portuguese/Spanish accents with jsPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898106/portuguese-spanish-accents-with-jspdf) but for me is still not working. i downloaded the file  from the master branch of the github project and no text is rendered correctly.

In my html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/jsPDF/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/scripts/jsPDF/jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script>
```

in my js file:

```
 var doc = new jsPDF('l','pt','letter');

   doc.setFontSize(15);
   doc.setFont("helvetica");

   doc.text(35, 65, "íóúáé"); //not rendering correctly

   doc.save("test.pdf");
```

**EDIT:** i solved this changing the line `<meta charset="utf-8">` for`<meta charset="iso-8859-1">`

Comment: i tried you code with latest jspdf (and anything else) and it worked just fine.

Comment: @enapupe you think it could be the jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js file?

Comment: IDK, have you tried using only the lastest pdfjs?

Comment: i think so, it says last commit was 2 months ago